# URL Rewriting issues with MVC and Application Request Routing (ARR)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-7, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-4.0

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using IIS Application Request Routing (ARR) for ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2245235/using-iis-application-request-routing-arr-for-asp-net-mvc)

I have an application in MVC3 running in IIS7 and another site running in different port. Certain links in my MVC application requires to show the static content from another site. Redirection was not a choice due to various constrains.

We tried to implement URL Rewriting in IIS7.

1. Written a rule to rewrite the URL for a pattern match
2. Installed Application Request Routing and enabled Proxy from ARR > Server Proxy Settings
3. Checked "Reverse rewrite host in response headers" from ARR > Server Proxy Settings
4. Application pool is running on .NET 4.0 in integrated mode

Unfortunately ARR routing is not working. I checked Failed Request Log and found that URL Rewrite is working as expected, but the routing is not happening.

Did any one faced this issue? Any clue?

Comment: *"...to show the static content from CMS site."* Do you mean that CMS content needs to be displayed within Asp.net MVC view (inside some container)?

Comment: Nop, my requirement is different. I just need to show the page from CMS site. It could be newsletter or bulletin or some marketing related page. Redirection will not work as the CMS site is behind the firewall (not in DMZ). So we thought to go with URL Rewriting.